# How to reuse value from a custom Views field handler in a second Views field?

Tags: views

I have a custom Views field handler:

```
function MY_MODULE _views_views_data() {

 $data['Customer']['Cust_Number'] = array(
    'field' => array(
      'title' => t('Customer Number'),
      'help' => t('This is the account number.'),
      'id' => 'numeric',
    ),
  );
```

I need to reuse the Cust_Number field in another, second field which will have a custom handler like:

```
  $data['Customer']['Cust_Number'] = array(
    'field' => array(
      'title' => t('Customer Next Service'),
      'help' => t('The customer next service date.'),
      'id' => 'customer_next_serv',
    ),
  );
```

Where this second has a custom id for its handler so I can use the base field value for a different, custom output.

I suspect it's not possible to have multiple fields for one table value, correct?

If not, is there another way to use the same table column field and have two different handlers for it (numeric and custom)?

Comment: Why not extend the second handler from the first one and then make it a configurable option which method, custom or parent, to use for displaying the field when you add the field to the View?

Comment: Thank you for the reply but you lost me on your suggestion. I'm pretty good at figuring things out without needing step by steps but this lost me. How would you 'extend' the second handler?

Comment: Is this D8 or D7?

Comment: Sorry. Drupal 8.

Comment: `class MyCustomNumericField extends NumericField` and override the method `render()` where you can call `parent::render()` for the original field handler code.